# Login is not executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've made a login page, but it isn't working.
My HTML is:

```
   <form name="form" class="login-form" method="POST"> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="userID" id="userID"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
      <input type="button" id="login" name="login" value="login" onclick="redirect()"></input>
```

My JS is:

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function redirect(){
        $("#login").click(function(){
        var user = $('#userID').val(); 
        var passwrd = $('#password').val();
        if (user === '' || passwrd === ''){
        alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
        } 
else{
        <?php confirm();?>
        var userID="<?php echo $username?>";
        var pwd="<?php echo $pwd?>";
        if(userID===user && pwd===passwrd)
        {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php';
        }
        else
      {
         alert("Please enter correct username and password!");
      }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And PHP is:

```
 <?php
      function confirm(){
        try{
        $username="";
        $pwd="";
        $pword="";
        $servername = "localhost";
        $conusername = "root";
        $conpassword = "";
        $dbname = "annapoorna";
        $dsn='mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$servername;
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $conusername, $conpassword);
        $get_pass=$_POST(['password']);
         if(!empty($get_pass))
         {
        $sqlselect='Select * from users where password=:pass';
        $sth=$conn->prepare($sqlselect);
        $sth->execute(array(':pass'=>$get_pass));
        foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $row) {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $pwd=$row['password'];
        }
        }
        } 
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
     }}
   ?>
```

It works only for a static value of password put in the query against ':pass'. Why is it not working dynamically? 
So I think the problem is in fetching data from front-end.
Pray, tell me what evil spirits are hovering over my code.

Comment: Side note, you should not be storing a password in plaintext. Check out `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: Let's not worry about the security. It should work in the first place.

Comment: You should use AJAX. You cannot call PHP functions directly from javascript.

Comment: @VineetBasantani Yeah, that's true, password security is over rated anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<form name="form" class="login-form" method="POST"> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="userID" id="userID"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
      <input type="button" id="login" name="login" value="login" onclick="redirect()"></input>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function redirect(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
        var user = $('#userID').val(); 
        var passwrd = $('#password').val();
        if (user === '' || passwrd === ''){
            alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
        } 
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "validate.php",
                type: "post",
                data : {
                    username: user,
                    password: passwrd
                },
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    if(data=="ok"){
                        window.location.href="http://localhost/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and validate.php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$conusername = "root";
$conpassword = "";
$dbname = "annapoorna";
$dsn='mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$servername;
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $conusername, $conpassword);

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];       

$sqlselect="Select * from users where username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";
$sth=$conn->prepare($sqlselect);
$sth->execute();

$status="";
foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $status="ok";
}
echo $status;
?>
```

Comment: you should edit your question and should not post a new question if you have one.

Comment: You are demonstrating a script that is introduces sql injection.

Comment: @mani j What should I write for 'url:' if both the php and script are in the same file?

Comment: create new php file in the name of validate.php and give that

Comment: Why can't I have them both in the same file?

Comment: @Rasclatt to avoid sql injection can use like the following     
  $sqlselect="Select * from users where username=:username' and password=:password";
        $sth=$conn->prepare($sqlselect);
        $sth->execute( array(':username' => $username, ':password'=>$password));

Comment: Okay, I did create another file. It displays 'ok' in an alert and nothing happens after that.

Comment: I will post another script paste it and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113376/discussion-between-mani-j-and-vineet-basantani).

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form using js or jquery. Try updating your code as below,

```
if(userID===user && pwd===passwrd)
{
    document.getElementById("formid").submit();
}
```

In php, remove the braces, change

```
$get_pass=$_POST(['password']);
```

to

```
$get_pass=$_POST['password'];
```